# changing or hiding urls using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have url like `http://localhost/site/blog.php?id=31` and id is being used on the page blog.php to get the content but i want to show the url like this `http://localhost/site/blog/id/31` for seo purpose.It is also fine if url displays like `localhost/site/id/3`1 or any other similar pattern. It is just that code which displays contents is in blog.php and it uses ID parameter to display contents. I have tried following methods but  nothing has worked so far. any help from all you experts out there?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ site/blog?id=$1 [QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?id/([^/]+)/?$ site/blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate ,

To display :

> localhost/site/id/3

Use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/id/([^/]*)$ /site/blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To display :

> localhost/site/blog/id/31

Use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/bog/id/([^/]*)$ /site/blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply mate i tried both but didn't work. :-(  not sure why, any idea?

Comment: Thanks for reply mate. I see it shows content with broken css when i enter in the url directly this http://localhost/site/blog/id/31. But what i was expecting is , when i enter this url http://localhost/site/blog.php?id=31 in the browser, it will automatically take me to this one http://localhost/site/blog/id/31 , as it happens in wordpress after changing permalinks. Is it possible?

Comment: i tried the same with my localhost but it works for me . can't figure what is blocking over there . few questions 1) Whether you put .htaccess in your main "site" folder 2) Whether you have any other rewrite / redirect in .htaccess 3) If yes , then whether you put this rule on top of that

Comment: 1. i am not putting .htaccess in site folder I am putting this in root. 2. I only have above code in .htaccess

Comment: @Dalip try putting .htaccess inside /site folder as its where the blog.php exists